# Is a (Dedicated) 4mbps line good enough for PS4?

Tags: ps4, networking, fortnite-battle-royale, apex-legends

Where I live, Internet services are very expensive and unfortunately I can't get the speeds people usually seem to have in America for a good price if at all they exist here. I've already tried using 4mbps and 10mbps lines (Shared) but I always seem to experience high packet loss during peak hours. I'm so tired of looking around for a solution. I've even gone to the extent of buying an xbox one only to find that it gives me the same problem. I'm thinking maybe a dedicated 4mbps line should solve this issue? It is so frustrating knowing that I can only play my online games 12am to 6am without any connection issues :(

I play games like Fortnite, Pugb and COD on PS4 and they all lag during the day and worse at peak hours.

What is a good internet connection bandwidth to play these games?

Comment: The problem might lie in the latency and quality of the connection rather than bandwidth,

Comment: Bandwidth requirements can vary substantially depending on game. (Remember people used to play online games on 56k modems just fine.) It all depends on how good the net code is and how much data needs to be synchronized between players. It might be worth adding the area you are trying to play from because that might give people an idea of the closest servers / players you are likely to be connecting to.

Answer (score 2):

Googling a bit regarding those games I've found that for example, Fortnite needs at least 3 Mbps download speed and 1 Mbps upload, but the best results come around 10 Mbps ([more info](https://www.phoenixinternet.com/what-internet-speed-do-i-need-to-play-fortnite/)), I believe that similar requirements are for similar games (unofficial data for PUBG recommended around 4 Mbps).

However, in online gaming, the bigger issue is latency and quality of the connection (number of lost packets, the stability of connection). The first one relates directly to your physical distance to server: for example, it is very hard to get ping below ~200 ms from New Zealand to any USA server, the second depends on your provider. Will it be better than shared 10 Mbps? Yes. Will it be enough for competitive gaming? Maybe.

Answer (score -1):

4MPBS is pretty good for games like Apex, Fortnite and PUBG. The problem might be your connection **quality** not your bandwidth. I recommend you get in touch with your Internet service provider and ask them.